# Trying to paginate scraped data

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm trying to get a list of links for each page I'm trying to scrape. I can get the required data from page1 but when I try and expand to other pages I am having a hard time. Can anyone point me in the right direction pls?

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession

s = HTMLSession()
def get_product_links(page):
  url = "https://lakesshoweringspaces.com/catalogue-product-filter/page/{page}"

  r = s.get(url)
  products = r.html.find("article.contentwrapper section.collection-wrapper-item")
  for item in products:
      res = links.append(item.find("a", first=True))
      if res:
        print(res.attrs["href"])
      else:
        print("no match")
  return links

  page1 = get_product_links(1)
  print(page1)
```

Comment: Could you expand your question? What's wrong and what are your desired results?

Comment: Apologies, I was tired last night and struggling to explain what I'm trying to do. I am trying to return a list of links that can be applied to multiple pages.  The goal is to extract data from each of the links on all of the pages. I created a function to take my code and run it over and over again for each page on the website. The above code can return each link from 1 page if you remove the function but the if / else is making it difficult for me to do it to all of the pages. I am new to Python so help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to have got this working:

```
from IPython.core.interactiveshell import page
from requests_html import HTMLSession

s = HTMLSession()
def get_product_links(page):
  url = f'https://lakesshoweringspaces.com/catalogue-product-filter/page/{page}'
  links = []
  r = s.get(url)
  products = r.html.find('article.contentwrapper section')
  for item in products:
    q = links.append(item.find("a", first=True))
    if q:
        print(q.attrs["href"]).text.strip()
    else:
        print("")
  return links


test_link = 'https://lakesshoweringspaces.com/catalogue_product/alassio/'

r = s.get(test_link)

print(r.html.find('div.product-sidecontent h3', first=True).text.strip())
```